# Cypress Test Runner open in Visual Studio runs old version of spec.js file

Tags: testing, cypress

When I open Cypress Test Runner via Visual Studio it runs old version of spec.js file.
First it starts loading newest version, but then it reloads and some old version of spec.js file is run. I run it on Windows 10.